# Accessing GSM Modem in C#

Tags: c#, gsm

I have a GSM modem which has a specific command set associated with it. I want to invoke those commands using my c# code. Is it possible to do this?

GSM modem model: MOD 9001 BENQ GSM/GPRS Modem

I dont have any library to interact with this modem

Comment: Could you provide a bit of more detail? Specifically what GSM model (make/model), what interfaces you have to it through code (.NET library/COM Interop) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any details for the specific modem you mention, the general approach to communicating with modems is to open a serial port connection and talk to the modem in plain text. Generally using some variant of the [Hayes command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set). For .NET, you might want to refer to `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)). The connection parameters (baud rate, data bits, stop bits, parity, flow control) depends on the modem but a good start is to try 57600, 8 databits, 1 stop bit, no parity and hardware flow control; those are typical parameters. The name of the port is highly dependent on how its connected to your system, but a good place to look if you don't know is the Windows Device Manager under COM ports.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is rather old, but fighting with my own modem with same reasons. I am using C# atm to access my own modem.

They way I connected to the modem was as mentioned before `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`. You have to tell it which COM port to connect to.

Assuming you have standard drivers for the modem installed and it is connected to computer you can get a list back of open COM ports by using:

```
string[] com_ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Assuming that you want to connect to the first COM port from the array above. Opening a port is a simple as:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.portname = com_ports[0];
// ... Insert other port parameters
port.Open();
```

Writing commands to modem is as simples as:

```
port.write("some command");
```

And response is comming back on:

```
String response = port.ReadExisting();
```

.. Just remember to add `"\r"` to the end of all commands to modem. Took me a day for me to find out, why-o-why my modem wasn't responding to my command... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    serialPort1 = new EnhancedSerialPort();
    serialPort1.PortName ="COM 11";  // check it in your case
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200; //suggested
    recievingBuffer = "";
    serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 400;
    serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 400;
```

to notice incoming calls:-

recievingBuffer += serialPort1.ReadExisting();

to active your GSM send following Command:-

serialPort1.Write("AT\r\n");