# how to extract the local time from gsm sim card by a gsm modem

Tags: c#

Is there any method to extract the time from sim card in c#? I am using it as a alternate for time synchronization where internet is not present.

> //----------- Edit 1 ----------------------------------- Till now i
>   have tried gsm library for sending and receiving of sms. But it doesnt
>   have any support to get time. I am using visual studio 2010, win form.
>   Its a pure desktop application

Kindly please dont close the question. Its a straight forward question, all i am getting the time from sim card.

Comment: What did you try? How do you connect the SIM Card to your PC? What Application did work on(Web or Form)? What API are you using if you 'just' looking for a method?

Answer (score 0):

If *both* the modem and the carrier support NITZ then it should be possible to get the network time using the correct AT commands.  Here's an example using a Telit GSM862 GSM module:

http://note19.com/2009/06/30/how-to-setup-network-time-on-telit-module/

The exact commands will depend on which GSM modem you are using.  You don't say which library you are using to send and receive SMS but if it doesn't directly support AT commands you might be interested in this:

[Accessing GSM Modem in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355974/accessing-gsm-modem-in-c-sharp)